# Left dropdown border not showing on page when I hover over button

Tags: css

Below is my code for the footer of a webpage I'm building:

```
<div class='footer'>
<footer class="page-footer font-small pt-4">
    <div class="container text-center text-md-left">
        <div class="row">
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li>
                    <a href="/" class="footerstyle">Hello</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="features" class="footerstyle">Hello</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="footer-dropdown footerstyle dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Team
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu sub-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="">Team members</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="">Our Story</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="">Join the team</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="" class="footerstyle">Hello</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="" class="footerstyle">Hello</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Below is the styling I've applied:

```
    .dropdown-item {
        font-family: Roboto-Regular;
        background-color: #F0F0F7;
    }

    .dropdown-item:hover {
        font-family: Roboto-Regular;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: #F0F0F7;
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
        font-family: Roboto-Regular;
        background-color: #F0F0F7;
        border-radius: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

When I hover over the dropdown menu it doesn't show left-most border of the dropdown box. How can I make it so that it shows up?

[image: Border not showing correctly]

Comment: add u r complete code

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: It looks like some part of your `.dropdown-item` may be overlapping the left side of your `.dropdown-menu`, however I can't test this because the code you included does not reproduce the example in the image. [This is what your sample code is producing](https://jsfiddle.net/ru2zsvac/). You'll need to include just enough css to reproduce the effect if you want others to help you troubleshoot effectively.